# PHP: list() set variables dynamically form string (read any CSV file as formatted order)

Tags: php, arrays, list, variables, foreach

Can I set variables names as csv title (first line)?

I do think it, so I code this:

```php
$string = "date, name, age"; // csv file title order format
$tit = explode(", ", $string); //array('date', 'name', 'age'); //will be called: $_date

//run php function to find a specific line
$arr = array('bash', 'monkey', 'badger'); //returned line
foreach ($tit as $i => $nam) { 
    $e = "_" . $nam; 
    $$e = $arr[$i];
} 
//set variables contents as title name
echo $_name; //monkey
```

Works perfectly: [Try it](https://tio.run/##ZVJNb4MwDL3zKywUKSAh0LZbU7rzLjvuMk0ogAvRwodC2q1q@9uZE7p2UyUkYvu95@c4YzvO8/p5bEdgvewQcuAPsJd6h1wAkw2CSz3eUrW0HvV0S03WqL6hZOiKCTihBIgbimC76yurhh7s8NKNeqgxuuBjOALTqseck8h2MCirNsLvBRQmQN8VKid/jo/Q6KGUGpgLxSIAab7EKT9xcQaDdmf6pUZhgFU7AH@TRslSIzkBz6KWnbQWaxhMjQbUtAKe3vtM@bo02YaLIMvYXpopZ4UflBV@UlbQqAIuVd/jlfI5X2Cep9VkI/avHtOFXac90bD3nWMRMKvsX@C/axGQZdIYeYi475QAd47cnyxxX/9SWkOJUEmtsV7BYipgxCPdC7uUU@tY3dB/4sGdSlk3aEgi@N2Md@L2oPKNeyu0C4Z5WISpi2gVzL0Lp/vO1Ic4L9e@tBPBPP8A)

But how to turn it into PHP function?

```php
function toList ($tit,$arr) {
    foreach ($tit as $i => $nam) { 
        $e = "_" . $nam; 
        $$e = $arr[$i];
    }
}

$tit = array('date', 'name', 'age'); //will be called as: $_date
$arr = array('bash', 'monkey', 'badger');
    
toList($tit,$arr);
    
echo $_date;
```

As function, code breaks.

How should code it to Php function works?

Comment: dont do it, use an array!! ;p or if you really have to, set it into `$GLOBALS["_".$nam] = $arr[$i];` `$$e` is not in scope if you use a function

Comment: why is not recommended to do it?

Comment: I don't have to... but why not to do?

Comment: is just poor practice, variable names should be concrete and easy to track or refactor throughout the app.. its alittle unclear what list() or csv has to do with variable variables and your code apart from you cant store multiple lines of a csv in a single var as a string without using an array